# Proving if n is odd there is m such that n=4m+1 or n=4m+3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if `n` is an odd integer then there is an integer `m` such that `n=4m+1` $or$ `n=4m+3`

Comment: What can you say about n-1 or n-3 for any n that is odd?

Comment: given any n that is odd, n-1 or n-3 is always an even number (?)

Comment: What can you say about the parity of  :i) $4n$ ii) $4n+2$ ?

Comment: @DBF It's always even?

Comment: Can either be odd? Remember that a number is even iff it is a multiple of 2 . Can you see that either of i), ii) are multiples of 2 ? Try factoring a 2 of both expressions.

Comment: (4n + 2) = 2(2n+1)
But I do not see the connection between that and my question.

Comment: Well, you can break down all numbers into either of : i)$4n$, ii)$4n+2$ , iii)$4n+1$ , iv)$4n+3$ . And i, ii) are even, so an odd number cannot be expressed as either i) or ii).

Comment: Where does the `m` come into play?

Comment: $m$ is the quotient in the standard division of $n$ by $4$ , with possible remainders $0,1,2,3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is odd. Then $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Now $k$ is either even or odd.

- If $k$ is even then $k=2m$ for some integer $m$;
- If $k$ is odd then $k=2m+1$ for some integer $m$.

Substitute these two expressions for $k$ in terms of $m$ into your expression for $n$ and watch what happens.

Comment: Re-read my question please. I made some changes.

Comment: @DiscreteGenius: My answer still answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be any integer. We then divide $m$ by $4$ , using the standard Euclidean algorithm , and we get:

```
$m=4q+r$ ;
```

$0 \leq r < 4$

Now, $m$ is divisible by $2$ iff $r=0,2$ . Then, if $m$ is not even, i.e., $m$ is odd, then $m$ must be of the form....